# Convert Image Band Values from Array into Number

Tags: google-earth-engine, raster-conversion, array

I am trying to convert the pixel values that appeared to be an array (see the snapshot below) into numeric. In its current state, every time I tried implementing reduction, I got an error:

> Input to Reducer.mean must be a numeric scalar, not
> Type<Float<dimensions=1>>.

Here's a snapshot of the console when I printed the data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, just found out that the function

> arrayFlatten

does the trick.